# Compare two ArrayList irrespective of order - Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Below are two list Some1 and Some which actually has same object data but different in order of elements in object and order of objects in array. My concern is below has to return true. Please favour

```
List<Some> lome1=new ArrayList<Some>();
          Some some1 = new Some();
          some1.setTime(1000);
          some1.setStartTime(25);
          some1.setEndTime(30);
            lome1.add(some1);
          Some some2 = new Some();
           some2.setStartTime(125);
          some2.setEndTime(130);
          some2.setTime(100);
          lome1.add(some2);

          List<Some> lome2=new ArrayList<Some>();
          Some some3 = new Some();
          some3.setStartTime(125);
          some3.setEndTime(130);
          some3.setTime(100);
          lome2.add(some3);
          Some some = new Some();

          some.setStartTime(25);
          some.setTime(1000);
          some.setEndTime(30);
         lome2.add(some);
```

Attempts which failed due to order:
With deepEquals:

```
if(Arrays.deepEquals(lome1.toArray(),lome2.toArray()) ){
            System.out.println("equal");
        }
          else {
              System.out.println("not equal");
          }
```

With hashset, both gave different hash value though data is same

```
if(new HashSet<>(lome1).equals(new HashSet<>(lome2)) ){
            System.out.println("equal");
        }
          else {
              System.out.println("not equal");
          }
```

Check if object is contained in another

```
boolean x=true
for(Some d: lome1) {

                  if(!lome2.contains(d)) {
                        x = false;
                  }
         }
          if(x){
            System.out.println("equal");
        }
          else {
              System.out.println("not equal");
          }
```

Comment: `containsAll()` method may be your answer?

Comment: Post code of `Some` class

Comment: it only has pojo of time, starttime and endtime

Answer (score 2):

First Override hashcode and equals for Some Object, It may look like this,

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Some that = (Some) o;
        return startTime == that.startTime &&
                endTime == that.endTime &&
                time == that.time
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(startTime, endTime, time);
    }
```

Once equals and Hashcode is set then different object with same values will give the same hashcode thus .equals() will return true

Now for the list use 
`list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1);`

Comment: I get classcast exception stating Some cannot be cast to Comparator

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the two lists as HashSets is probably the best approach, since that works irrespective of the order.

However, your HashSet comparison is dependent on you implementing the equals() and hashCode() functions in your "Some" class. You've not provided the source for that, so I'm guessing you've missed that. Without overriding those methods in your class, the JRE doesn't know that two Some objects are the same or not.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getTime() + getStartTime() + getEndTime();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Some) {
        Some other = (Some)o;
        if (getTime() == other.getTime()
                && getStartTime() == other.getStartTime()
                && getEndTime() == other.getEndTime()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `containsAll()` API provided by java collection.
`lome1.containsAll(lome)` should do the trick.

Comment: containsAll is for collections, isn't it ?

Comment: i still get not equal

Comment: have you implemented the equals method of Some?

Comment: `a.containsAll(b)` returning true could also mean that a is a superset of b, thus not actually equal.

Comment: How your equals method in Some looks like?

Answer (score 0):

For Java 1.8+ you could check that each element of first list is in the second and vice versa:

```
        boolean equals = lome1.stream().allMatch(e -> lome2.contains(e)) &&
            lome2.stream().allMatch(e -> lome1.contains(e));
```

Comment: Obviously, equals/hashCode for Some should be overriden for instance as Drewll posted.

Answer (score 0):

Do Something like this

```
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new User("User","20"));
        list.add(new User("Some User","20"));
        List<User> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

        list1.add(new User("User","20"));
        list1.add(new User("Some User","20"));

        List<User> storeList = new ArrayList<>();


        for (User user: list){
            for (User user1:list1){
                if (user.getName().equals(user1.getName()) && user.getAge().equals(user1.getAge()))
                    storeList.add(user);
            }
        }

        boolean check = !storeList.isEmpty();
       //OR


        check = storeList.size() == list.size();

        System.out.println(check);
```